# compilation TypeError: Function has non-object prototype 'null' in instanceof check

Tags: javascript, webpack, compilation, hook

macos
webpack5
make a new plugin,use a hook thisCompilation and tap it. In the callback log the arameter 'compilation'. But show me a error "Function has non-object prototype 'null' in instanceof check"

```js
class Plugin2 {
  apply( compiler ) {
    compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap( 'Plugin2', ( compilation ) => {
      console.log( 'compilation' ) // its worked
      console.log( compilation ) // Error

    } )
  }
}

module.exports = Plugin2
```

Error info:

```js
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Function has non-object prototype 'null' in instanceof check
        at Function.[Symbol.hasInstance] (<anonymous>)
        at getConstructorName (internal/util/inspect.js:545:13)
        at formatRaw (internal/util/inspect.js:813:23)
        at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:803:10)
        at formatProperty (internal/util/inspect.js:1689:11)
        at formatRaw (internal/util/inspect.js:1017:9)
        at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:803:10)
        at formatProperty (internal/util/inspect.js:1689:11)
        at formatRaw (internal/util/inspect.js:1017:9)
        at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:803:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update node to fix it.My node verssion is low
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35730